# JDK GC parameters: Issue with GC[YG occupancy...]]

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

Our application takes 25-35 seconds everytime and throws issue at `GC[YG occupancy..]]`

Our GC parameters are set according to the available memory but application is stopped for said timings.

JDK Version: `1.6`

GC parameters are:

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:NewSize=600m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=600m 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=3
-XX:+CMSPrecleanRefLists1
-XX:+CMSPrecleanRefLists2
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:PrintCMSStatistics=2 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:CMSMarkStackSize=4m 
-XX:CMSMarkStackSizeMax=516m 
-XX:ParGCDesiredObjsFromOverflowList=20k
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=65
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow 
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=6g
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

Please help, GC logs are:

```
2014-08-16T06:51:02.054-0400: 80744.151: [GC[YG occupancy: 5263K (83891K)]2014-08-16T06:51:02.054-0400: 80744.151: [GC 80744.151: [ParNew: 5263K->4505K(83891K), 0.0454870 secs] 22835786->2282820K(3334476K), 0.0456220 secs] [Times: user=0.74 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
80744.197: [Rescan (parallel)  (Survivor:28chunks) Finished young gen rescan work in 5th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 6th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 9th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 12th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 4th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 13th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 10th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 2th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 14th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 15th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 16th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 17th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 17th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 9th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 5th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 13th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 6th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 14th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 15th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 4th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 16th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 2th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 1th thread: 0.001 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 1th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 10th thread: 0.001 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 8th thread: 0.002 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 8th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 7th thread: 0.003 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 7th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 0th thread: 0.005 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 0th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 12th thread: 0.008 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 14th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 6th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 2th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 1th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 0th thread: 0.005 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 10th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 17th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 7th thread: 0.007 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 15th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 9th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 12th thread: 0.002 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 16th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 5th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 13th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 4th thread: 0.009 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 8th thread: 0.008 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 3th thread: 0.031 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 3th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 3th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished young gen rescan work in 11th thread: 0.047 sec
Finished remaining root rescan work in 11th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished dirty card rescan work in 11th thread: 0.000 sec
Finished work stealing in 1th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 11th thread: 24.897 sec
Finished work stealing in 2th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 6th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 5th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 0th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 16th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 8th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 4th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 15th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 9th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 14th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 3th thread: 24.913 sec
Finished work stealing in 17th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 7th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 12th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 10th thread: 24.934 sec
Finished work stealing in 13th thread: 24.934 sec
, 24.9444010 secs]80769.141: [weak refs processing, 0.0053080 secs]80769.146: [class unloading, 0.0244670 secs]80769.171: [scrub symbol & string tables, 0.0307390 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 2278315K(3250585K)] 2282820K(3334476K), 25.0603030 secs] [Times: user=449.55 sys=0.11, real=25.06 secs] 
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 25.0614090 seconds
```

Comment: some of those options seem to be based very old, possibly outdated advise, have you tried without most of those options? And you didn't state which JVM version you're using either.

Comment: We are using JDK 1.6, edited question. Thanks.

Comment: The operating system may sawp heap on disk. Can you try to disable swap?
This can be done:
**sudo swapoff -a**

Comment: Try to use a memory profiling tool to have a look what is in the heap at that point. These things are really hard to diagnose otherwise. Also, setting GC parameters might do more damage than good if not done properly!!! How did you come to this configuration? Why is it better in your case?

Comment: Configurations are built over the period of time as part of tuning activities. How can I setup memory profiling on the running code in UAT environment? May be I can do it locally, but any guidance on how to do it in higher environments?